# Passing a variable from one function to another function

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope, argument-passing

I have a function with way to much going on in it so I've decided to split it up into smaller functions and call all my block functions inside a single function. --> e.g.

```
def main_function(self):
  time_subtraction(self)
  pay_calculation(self,todays_hours)
```

and -->

```
def time_subtraction(self):
    todays_hours = datetime.combine(datetime(1,1,1,0,0,0), single_object2) - datetime.combine(datetime(1,1,1,0,0,0),single_object)
    return todays_hours
```

So what im trying to accomplish here is to make `todays_hours` available to my `main_function`. I've read lots of documentation and other resources but apparently I'm still struggling with this aspect.

**EDIT**--
This is not a method of the class. Its just a file where i have a lot of functions coded and i import it where needed.

Comment: What's the problem with just storing the result? `todays_hours = time_subtraction(self)`?

Comment: If these are not methods, why have you named the first argument `self`? That's going to mislead anyone who reads it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass the return value of one function to another, you need to either nest the function calls:

```
pay_calculation(self, time_subtraction(self))
```

… or store the value so you can pass it:

```
hours = time_subtraction(self)
pay_calculation(self, hours)
```

---

As a side note, if these are methods in a class, you should be calling them as `self.time_subtraction()`, `self.pay_calculation(hours)`, etc., not `time_subtraction(self)`, etc. And if they *aren't* methods in a class, maybe they should be.

Often it makes sense for a function to take a Spam instance, and for a method of Spam to send `self` as the first argument, in which case this is all fine. But the fact that you've defined `def time_subtraction(self):` implies that's not what's going on here, and you're confused about methods vs. normal functions.

Comment: Much appreciated my friend, valid points. + 1 for giving answer i feel like i knew but just didnt think to do it that way lol.